# paypal website form return parameters with link and auto return

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I choose "on" for auto return from my selling tools:
https://www.paypal.com/webapps/customerprofile/

But auto return is not working! why?

and this my form:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="example@mail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">              
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.01">
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://example.com/done.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://example.com/cancel.php">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy">
    </form>
```

now my return page not has parameters like this:
http://example.com/done.php?tx=XXXX&st=Completed&amt=200.00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=7

I need auto return and paramteres!

Help me.

Comment: Where do you set `$name` and `$id`. Also it is not a good practice to use PHP tags everywhere. It is better to use PHP on whole document and echo out HMTL.

Comment: @EvanCarslake I'm not sure that's true, echoing out the HTML in the PHP would make it much less readable, and harder to manage. It's quite common for PHP to be echo'ed out like this, particularly in templates.

Answer (score 0):

- Most Likely, you did not enable [Payment Data Transfer](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/)(PDT).
- You enabled PDT, but if transaction is made via Credit card, you will need to manually click on "return to merchant site" link to get redirected 
  to your return URL which means auto-return only works if payment is made via paypal account.

**Steps to enable PDT**

-Login to your PayPal account

-click on Profile

-click 'My selling preferences

-click on Update next to Website preferences

-Go to the Payment Data Transfer Section

-Choose Payment Data Transfer ON and the Token will be displayed below

[PDT Sample codes](https://github.com/paypal/pdt-code-samples)

Comment: How to eanble PTD? I don't know how to enable it! I open your link developer.paypal.com but i don't understand :(

Comment: Ok I enabled it but paramerers not showing after buying using my form, look to my form at top.

Comment: read this link  https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/

you will need to setup your code to make it work and check my answer for PDT sample code.

Comment: I don't understand any thing :(
I need simple form like this demo: http://demos.9lessons.info/paypal/products.php